# What are your tricks for optimizing your Subversion configuration?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, performance-tuning

For a Linux or Windows system, what tricks do you do to optimize your Subversion server?

The following are my current tricks for a Linux system serving over Apache with HTTPS and backed by Active Directory using LDAP authentication.

- [Enabling KeepAlive on Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalive)
- [Disable SVNPathAuthz](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html)
- [Increase LDAP Cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ldap.html)
- Using the FSFS storage method instead of BDB

  - Feel free to call this into question.  I don't have hard proof that FSFS out performs BDB, only lots of tribal knowledge and hearsay.

Comment: thanks for the reminder about KeepAlive!
It is indeed very helpful: I am presently doing svnsync between europe and Asia, and 'KeepAlive On' doubled the performance!

Answer (score 6):

I can't say much about the performance difference between BDB and FSFS, but I can definitely say that FSFS is far more stable.  I'd suggest using it over BDB simply to preserve your sanity.  When we had a largish repos running on BDB, we had to run recovery on it at least once a week, often several times.  It was irritating.  Now that we use FSFS, it's been rock solid.

Comment: +1 I wish I could give you more votes. If you're using BDB, you're doing it wrong. Had so many problems when using BDB. Since using fsfs, we've had none.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've been running FSFS for the past 3 years, when ever it switched over to the default, so haven't hit such an situation (thankfully). Good to know I shouldn't bother. :D

Comment: One of the primary reasons for me using SVN was that it had FSFS repos. I use to build the bleeding edge just for this feature.

Answer (score 5):

`"svnadmin pack"` is a neglected documentation command, but ran it often may be helpful especially if your commits are small.

Comment: Excellent, this feature is under-documented but I found some good information at http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2009/03/subversion-16-feature-preview-fsfs-packing.html

Comment: @Scott Markwell The updated link is http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2009/03/subversion-16-feature-preview-fsfs-packing/ (you'll be prompted to login at the above).

Answer (score 0):

I measured significant performance improvements when using svnserve instead of mod_dav_svn and Apache.

I performed some measurements in order to analyse repository performance in a project I'm working in, and the result was to setup an svnserve server in addition to the previously used Apache server. See http://www.ohrner.net/software/tipps_en.php, Section "Subversion Performance" for reference and measurement results.

I realise that using svnserve is not always an option, but often it is, at least if used in addition to WebDAV / DeltaV access, and if it is, it may be rewarding.

Gunter Ohrner